# For any subset H in a Group G, does H necessarily share the same binary operation as G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I think this might border somewhat a 'stupid' question but could I have some confirmation?

Comment: The multiplication on $G$ restricted to a subset $H$ is not necessarily an operation on $H$. This because it might occur that $h_1.h_2\notin H$ for some ordered pair $\langle h_1,h_2\rangle\in H\times H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put any binary operation you like on the subset, but from the point of view of group theory there will be nothing to mark it out as a 'subset of $G$'.  That is why, for the definition of *subgroup* we insist that the binary operation on $H$ is the operation inherited from $G$.

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then we have an injective homomorphism
$$
H\to G\\
x\mapsto x
$$

But there is nothing of this kind for an arbitrary group structure on the subset $H$.

Comment: My book provides the definition of the one-step subgroup test as follows:

Let G be a group and H a non-empty subset of G. Then, H is a subgroup of G if ab^{-1} is in H whenever a and b are in H.

Proof: Since the operation of H is the same as that of G, it is clear that this operation is associative.....

This is where the author is driving me into a confusion. Is there something I am not seeing that I do understand the first liner of the proof given?

Comment: @Mathematicing Perhaps your book could have stated this a bit more carefully.  The full statment is: if $G$ is a group and $H$ is a non-empty subset of $G$ such that $ab^{-1}$ is in $H$ for all $a,b\in H$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if we equip it with the operation inherited from $G$.

Answer (score 1):

No. A subset is a subset. It does not need to have certain properties of the superset. Of course, a subset of $G$ *could* be a subgroup and thus share the same binary operation as $G$. It all depends on how you define the subset.

For example, $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ is a group under addition. But the subset $\mathbb{Z}^* = \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ is not, because there is no neutral element.

Answer (score 1):

For the case where the subset H has sufficient structure to be a subgroup of G, by definition the subgroup H will have the same binary operation as the group G.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are asking whether the binary operation on $G$ restricts to a binary operation on $H$. Here the answer is no: applying the binary to two elements of $H$ may produce an element of $G$. Thus it becomes a partially defined binary operation on $H$.

It turns out that partial binary operations are still useful and interesting: instead of groups, you obtain [groupoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid)!